# How to display a form from another object using workflow in openerp

Tags: odoo

I am not a python programmer so please bear with me.

In OpenERP Manufacturing module, after I click the Produce button, a wizard pops out asking the mode and quantity, then you can confirm the production. I would like to insert another workflow to display the Stock Moves form after the user pressed the Confirm button.

here is my current python code:

class mrp_production(osv.osv_memory):

```
 _inherit = 'mrp.production'

def confirm_produce(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    obj_model = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    model_data_ids = obj_model.search(cr,uid,[('model','=','ir.ui.view'),('name','=','stock.move.tree')])
    return {
        'name': 'Stock Move',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'res_model': 'stock.move',
        'view_id' : model_data_ids,
        'search_view_id' : 'stock.view_move_search',
        'context': {'search_default_ready':1},
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

mrp_production()

Then I insert the action confirm_produce() in the Done activity of the Workflow using the web client after I installed the module.

However, when I run the production order then produce the product and confirm the quantity, nothing happens. No windows pops out. I expect to have a new window displaying the Stock Moves.

Answer (score 0):

modify the value of 'view_mode' to 'tree,form'